# git rebase onto different branch after already merged

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I am using the git adapter for Visual Studio. This question is about rebasing onto a different branch after it has already been merged to a branch.

We have a feature branch (I am the only developer to use it). A while ago it was merged into our Develop branch, along with a bunch of other feature branches before and after it. The client has decided to postpone the release of most of the work on our Develop branch and release what is on the feature branch by its self.

What I want to do is rebase the feature branch onto our previous release branch and create a new release branch from there. Will that work? 
The feature branch has newer code than the previous release branch. But I am assuming rebase won't care, it will only rebase the changes I made onto the old release branch?
I assume the Develop branch would be unaffected ?(which would be fine since we would have to merge the new release branch to develop anyway before it is put into a release.)

- Release 10
- New work done after Release 10 and merged to Develop branch
- Feature 88 created from Develop
- Feature 88 merged to Develop
- More features merged to Develop
- *What I want to do is rebase Feature 88 onto Release 10. And then create Release 11 from it.
  Assumption is Develop branch is unaffected and rebase will be fine with applying committed work only onto the Release 10 branch?

Eventually Release 11 work will be merged to Develop branch and it will be used for Release 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the reasons to use feature branches.

Suppose your feature branch is made up of 5 commits. You can move it anywhere like this:

```
git rebase --onto new-base feature-branch~5 feature-branch
```

That is assuming that your feature branch has no merges and is a straight line.

Now, your workflow is a little clearer like this:

```
git checkout -b release11 release 10
git rebase --onto release11 feature-branch~5 feature-branch
```

That will move the feature branch from the current position.... you might consider checking out and work detached.

```
git checkout --detach feature-branch
git rebase --onto release11 HEAD~5 HEAD
```

That should do